# Unable to get part of a play to run locally on AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

This is all running within AWX which is hosted on-prem. I'm trying to manage some EC2 instances within AWS. I've setup the bastion jump and can get all my other plays to work correctly.

However there is one simple job template I want to provide to a few devs. Essentially when they make a change to the code, it enables opcache to be cleared and invalidates the specific files in CloudFront.

I want the CloudFront API Call (cloudfront_invalidations module) to run off AWX locally and then if this is successful, notify the two web servers instances to restart their PHP and Apache process.

```
---
- name: Restart httpd and php-fpm
  remote_user: ec2-user
  hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Invalidate paths in CloudFront
      cloudfront_invalidation:
        distribution_id: "{{ distribution_id }}"
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
        target_paths: "{{ cloudfront_invalidations.split('\n') }}"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      notify:
        - Restart service httpd
        - Restart service php-fpm
  
  handlers:
    - name: Restart service httpd
      service:
        name: httpd
        state: restarted

    - name: Restart service php-fpm
      service:
        name: php-fpm
        state: restarted
```

However when running the play it seems to ignore the 'delegate_to' action and instead runs the invalidation twice, for each host. I'm unsure if it's actually running locally. I've tried adding the run_once flag, but this only then restarted httpd + PHP on one host.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

All tasks are applied to all hosts, even when you delegate it to localhost. If you have 2 hosts, then the tasks are running twice on localhost. You can use `run_once` to apply the task only to the first host in "all".

```
tasks:
  - name: Invalidate paths in CloudFront
    cloudfront_invalidation:
      distribution_id: "{{ distribution_id }}"
      aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
      target_paths: "{{ cloudfront_invalidations.split('\n') }}"
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
    run_once: true
    notify:
      - Restart service httpd
      - Restart service php-fpm
```

See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#running-on-a-single-machine-with-run-once for more details.